# Can't print char after using it in a function

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, switch-statement

I have an input which is Number1,Number2Command, for example 1,3c 1,5d  10,40p, I want to pass "command" to the function and have it back with the value c,d,p... In my code there is something wrong with strpbrk (which returns a pointer) because I can't print command.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef enum Command
{
    ChangeCommand = 'c',
    DeleteCommand = 'd',
    PrintCommand = 'p',
    UndoCommand = 'u',
    RedoCommand = 'r',
} Command;
char input[1025];
void funzione(int *val1, int *val2, char command){
    fgets(input, 1025, stdin);
    if (input[0] == 'q')
    {
        exit(2);
    }
    char *pEnd;
    *val1 = strtol(input, &pEnd, 10);
    *val2 = strtol(pEnd + 1, &pEnd, 10);
    char letters[5] = "crpud";
    command = strpbrk(input, letters);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int val1;
    int val2;
    char command;
    funzione(&val1, &val2, command);
    printf("%d %d %c", val1, val2, command);
    switch (command)
        {
        case ChangeCommand:
   
            break;

        case DeleteCommand:
            
            break;

        case PrintCommand:
       
            break;

        case UndoCommand:
     
            break;

        case RedoCommand:
      
            break;
        default:
            exit(1);
            break;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please submit a *minimally reprodicible example*.

Comment: Pay attention to your compiler warnings. There are many that should be resolved and may solve your error.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore no errors, that's the problem.

Comment: I see multiple *warnings*.

Comment: Remember there's difference between _errors_ and _warnings_.

Comment: ok thank you, string.h was missing, now i have one last warning, warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast, i don't know how to resolve this, i know that strpbrk return a pointer, but i don't know how to take that value and put it in command!

Comment: Why didn't you use a pointer for `command` while using ones for `val1` and `val2`?

Answer (score 1):

- [`strpbrk()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strpbrk) returns a pointer, so dereference that to get a value.
- The argument `command` should be a pointer like `val1` and `val2` to have it pass information to `main()`.
- There are no terminating null-character in `letters`, so using it to where string is expected is dangerous.

Fixed code:

```
void funzione(int *val1, int *val2, char *command){ /* add * before command */
    /* omitted, same as original */
    char letters[] = "crpud"; /* remove explicit size to have it calculate including terminating null-character */
    char* p_command = strpbrk(input, letters); /* obtain a pointer */
    *command = p_command != NULL ? *p_command : '\0'; /* dereference it (avoid dereferencing NULL) */
}
```

And

```
funzione(&val1, &val2, command);
```

in `main()` should be

```
funzione(&val1, &val2, &command);
```

with `&` added before `command`.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, the compiler gives you warnings for a reason.
What you are doing with `command = strpbrk(input, letters)` is casting a `char*` (what `strpbrk()` returns) to a `char` (what `command` is).

That aside, doing

```c
char letters[5] = "crpud";
command = strpbrk(input, letters);
```

finds the first occurrence of "crpud" inside of `input`. I think what you want is the first occurrence of 'c' or 'r' or 'p' or 'u' or 'd' in `input`.
Here's one way to solve this:

```c
void funzione(int *val1, int *val2, char *command){
    fgets(input, 1025, stdin);
    if (input[0] == 'q')
    {
        exit(2);
    }
    char *pEnd;
    *val1 = strtol(input, &pEnd, 10);
    *val2 = strtol(pEnd + 1, &pEnd, 10);
    char letters[5] = "crpud";
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) 
    {
        if (strchr(input, letters[i])) 
        {
            *command = letters[i];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use `funzione()` with a pointer to `command`:

```c
int val1;
int val2;
char command;
funzione(&val1, &val2, &command);
```